# Как при переопределении build() макета добавить данные в шаблон?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно как то при определении макета `var MyLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(...,{ build() {...}, ...})` в переопределяемом методе build() пробросить в шаблон дополнительные данные?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готового механизма нет, но зная, что [`templateLayoutFactory.createClass`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/templateLayoutFactory-docpage/#.createClass) возвращает [`ILayout`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ILayout-docpage/) (а конкретно [`layout.templateBased.Base`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layout.templateBased.Base-docpage/)), можно созданный класс динамически обернуть и переопределить в нем все места, где в макет передаются данные.

```js
ymaps.ready(['templateLayoutFactory', 'util.defineClass']).then(function() {
  var MyLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('x: {{x}} y: {{y}}');
  
  // Оборачиваем в класс подмменяющий данные.
  MyLayout = wrapWithDataSubstitution(MyLayout, function(data) {
    // data - чужой объект, лучше его не менять.
    return Object.assign({}, data, { y: 2 });
  });
  
  // Вызывающая часть.
  var layout = new MyLayout({ x: 1 });
  layout.setParentElement(document.getElementById('result'));
}).catch(console.error);

function wrapWithDataSubstitution(Layout, substitute) {
  // 1. Layout'ы принимают данные в конструкторе, подменим их до того как
  // они дойдут до layout.templateBased.Base.
  var Wrapper = function(data) {
    var rest = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    Wrapper.superclass.constructor.apply(this, [substitute(data)].concat(rest));
  };

  ymaps.util.defineClass(Wrapper, Layout, {
    // 2. Layout'ам можно менять данные через setData, переопределим
    // setData, чтобы подменять в нем данные.
    setData: function (data) {
      Wrapper.superclass.setData.call(this, substitute(data));
    }
  });
  
  return Wrapper;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Когда определял свой layout для метки, у меня проходил такой код

```
    iconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<img src="mark.png"
 class="mapobject" style="transform: rotate($[properties.rotation]deg);z-index:1000;"/>')
```

**$[properties.rotation]** заменяется на значение rotation из properties.

То есть заданные для объекта свои, любые, properties могут передаваться в назначенный объекту Layout.
Другой вопрос, что у Вас балун, а для него сложнее задавать properties.