# Как передавать дополнительную информацию (property) в multiroute?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как передавать дополнительную информацию (property) в multiroute для дальнейшего отображения в ballone?

Answer (score 2):

Стандартной возможности нет. Вы можете переопределить данные в макете (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754626/222907) и прокинуть туда что угодно.

Писать в свойства мультимаршрута (`multiRoute.properties`) не советую, т.к. они автоматически меняются при перестроении маршрута.

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', { center: [55.768, 37.62], zoom: 12, controls: [] });
  var route;
  
  var balloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass([
    '<div class="my-balloon">',
      '{{ customProperties.routeName }}, всего {{ properties.duration.text }}',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''));
  
  balloonLayout = wrapWithDataSubstitution(balloonLayout, function (data) {
    return Object.assign({}, data, { customProperties: route.customProperties });
  });
  
  route = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
    { referencePoints: ['Москва, Курский вокзал', 'Москва, Улица 1905 года'] },
    { balloonLayout: balloonLayout, balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0 });
  
  map.geoObjects.add(route);
  
  route.customProperties = new ymaps.data.Manager();
  route.customProperties.set('routeName', 'Мой любимый маршрут');
});


// Смотри https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754626/222907
function wrapWithDataSubstitution(Layout, substitute) {
  // 1. Layout'ы принимают данные в конструкторе, подменим их до того как
  // они дойдут до layout.templateBased.Base.
  var Wrapper = function(data) {
    var rest = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    Wrapper.superclass.constructor.apply(this, [substitute(data)].concat(rest));
  };

  ymaps.util.defineClass(Wrapper, Layout, {
    // 2. Layout'ам можно менять данные через setData, переопределим
    // setData, чтобы подменять в нем данные.
    setData: function (data) {
      Wrapper.superclass.setData.call(this, substitute(data));
    }
  });
  
  return Wrapper;
}
```

```css
.my-balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&mode=debug"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 180px;"></div>
```